# refactoring ruby methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have the following code in my notification model in my rails app.

I'd like to refactor it a bit. What is wrong for sure is this "check if object exists then do something with it" part. I guess I could use `try` but I don't know how it exactly works. Can sby tell me how to do that (with `try` or if there is a better way then with that)?

Any other observations regarding the rest of the code?

```
#check and decrease chat notification that happens between 2 given users (since 1v1 chat notification number max limit is 1)
def self.decreasing_chat_notification_number(current_user, user)
  if self.between_chat_recipient(current_user, user).unchecked.any?
    notification = self.between_chat_recipient(current_user, user).unchecked.first
    checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  end
end

#check and decrease all the task notifications that happens between 2 given users
def self.decreasing_task_notification_number(current_user, user)
  if self.task.between_other_recipient(current_user, user).unchecked
    self.task.between_other_recipient(current_user, user).unchecked.each do |notification|
      checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
    end
  end
end

#check and decrease all the post notifications that happened on a given post
def self.decreeasing_post_notification_number(current_user, post)
  if self.post.this_post_comments(current_user, post).unchecked
    self.post.this_post_comments(current_user, post).unchecked.each do |notification|
      checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
    end
  end
end

private

def check_notification #chat notification gets checked
  if self.checked_at == nil
    update_attributes(checked_at: Time.zone.now)
  end
end

def checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  notification.check_notification
  current_user.decrease_new_other_notifications
  current_user.decreased_other_number_pusher
end
```

scopes:

```
scope :not_chat, -> { where.not(notifiable_type: "Message") }
scope :chat, -> { where(notifiable_type: "Message") }
scope :task, -> { where(notifiable_type: "Task") }
scope :post, -> { where(notifiable_type: "Post") }
scope :checked, -> { where.not(checked_at: nil) }
scope :unchecked, -> { where(checked_at: nil) }
scope :this_post_comments, -> (recipient_id, post_id) do
  where("notifications.recipient_id = ? AND notifications.notifiable_id = ?", recipient_id, post_id)
end
scope :between_chat_recipient, -> (recipient_id, sender_id) do
  where("notifications.recipient_id = ? AND notifications.sender_id = ? AND notifications.notifiable_type = ?", recipient_id, sender_id, "Message")
end
scope :between_other_recipient, -> (recipient_id, sender_id) do
  where("notifications.recipient_id = ? AND notifications.sender_id = ?", recipient_id, sender_id)
end
```

UPDATE:

Everything is called on current_user as instance method instead of Notification.class_method. Btw. user table has `"new_chat_notification",default: 0` and `"new_other_notification", default: 0` attributes to count the number of current notifications.

user.rb

```
  #check and decrease chat notification that happens between 2 given users (max 1)
  def decreasing_chat_notification_number(user)
    notification = self.notifications.between_chat_recipient(user).unchecked.first
    self.checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification) if notification.present?
  end

  #check and decrease task notifications that happens between 2 given users
  def decreasing_task_notification_number(user)
    self.notifications.task.between_other_recipient(user).unchecked.each do |notification|
      self.checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
    end
  end

  #check and decrease the post notification that belongs to a given post
  def decreasing_post_notification_number(post_id)
    self.notifications.this_post_comments(post_id).unchecked.each do |notification|
      self.checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
    end
  end

  def checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
    notification.check_notification
    if notification.notifiable_type == "Message"
      self.decrease_new_chat_notifications
      self.decreased_chat_number_pusher
    else
      self.decrease_new_other_notifications
      self.decreased_other_number_pusher
    end
  end

  def decrease_new_chat_notifications
    decrement!(:new_chat_notification) if self.new_chat_notification > 0
  end


  def decrease_new_other_notifications
    decrement!(:new_other_notification) if self.new_other_notification > 0
  end

  def decreased_chat_number_pusher
    number = self.new_chat_notification
    Pusher['private-'+ self.id.to_s].trigger('new_chat_notification', {:number => number})
  end

  def decreased_other_number_pusher
    number = self.new_other_notification
    Pusher['private-'+ self.id.to_s].trigger('new_other_notification', {:number => number})
  end
```

notification.rb

```
scope :not_chat, -> { where.not(notifiable_type: "Message") }
scope :chat, -> { where(notifiable_type: "Message") }
scope :task, -> { where(notifiable_type: "Task") }
scope :post, -> { where(notifiable_type: "Post") }
scope :checked, -> { where.not(checked_at: nil) }
scope :unchecked, -> { where(checked_at: nil) }

scope :this_post_comments, -> (post_id) do
  where("notifications.notifiable_id = ?", post_id)
end

scope :between_chat_recipient, -> (sender_id) do
  where("notifications.sender_id = ? AND notifications.notifiable_type = ?", sender_id, "Message")
end

scope :between_other_recipient, -> (sender_id) do
  where("notifications.sender_id = ? AND notifications.notifiable_type != ?", sender_id, "Message")
end

def check_notification #chat notification gets checked
  update_attribute(:checked_at, Time.zone.now) if self.checked_at.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try` to try and send a message to an object. If the object responds to it, then it will be executed, if not it will be disregarded.

```
string = "foo"
string.try(:length) # => 3
nil.try(:length) => nil
```

I suggest you use `try!` instead. It will raise if receiver does not respond to the message AND is not `nil`

But that will not help you much here.

If you iterate, you will not need to check if something exists. You can just iterate and if the association is "empty", then nothing will happen.

So for example you can rewrite the `decreeasing_post_notification_number`:

```
def self.decreeasing_post_notification_number(current_user, post)
  self.post.this_post_comments(current_user, post).unchecked.each do |notification|
    checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  end
end
```

Same goes for `decreasing_chat_notification_number` IFF it is ok to call `checking_and_decreasing_notification` for `each` and not just `first`

Since we don't see the full code here i have to take some assumptions. The code does not look OO (you have `self` method that receives all the required values as params). I'd suggest you refactor it to either:

- Make this methods a behavior (method) of the relevant models
- Make a Service which covers a single business operation

BTW: Cool that you use `Time.zone.now` and not just `Time.now`!

Comment: Even if it's not ok to iterate on the decreasing notification I'd get rid of the check where it runs the query.  `notification = self.between_chat_recipient(current_user, user).unchecked.first` then `checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification) if notification.present?`

Comment: @j-dexx empty string `""` might be a legit value ⇒ `s/present/nil/`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I assume unchecked is a scope, and therefore he's getting an instance of the `Notification` class.

Comment: Updated with scopes! Pascal, could you pls a bit elaborate this part?: (you have `self` method that receives all the required values as params) + Make this methods a behavior (method) of the relevant models. I mean, I use those mainly on the notification model scopes, so for me methods seem to belong to their on model.

Comment: The methods are static (self). So all data they operate on is passed in as an argument. This is either users or posts. So you could move those methods into either User or Post. And only pass in one argument.

Static methods are usually harder to test and refactor so i try to code without.

Comment: Do you know a good resource to read about this? I'd dig in right away.

Comment: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/11/14/why-ruby-class-methods-resist-refactoring/

And static methods tend to behave unexpected when inheritance comes into play.

Comment: Pascal, I have updated my question with the refactored version (below UPDATE). Could you take a look at it? I'd like to know if I'm going the right way.

Comment: Looks better to me!

You can leave out "self" unless required (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required)

The name of the pusher channel is not "secure". Should this be a requirement you'd need to make something smarter there (i.e. use SecureRandom.hex or similar)

The differentiation of "chat" and "other" message types leads to some duplication and if switches. Perhaps you can come up with something better there? Perhaps add the increase/decrease methods to Message itself and let it decide what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with moving checks inside helpers:

```
def checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  return if notification.nil? # here we defend from bad input

  notification.check_notification
  current_user.decrease_new_other_notifications
  current_user.decreased_other_number_pusher
end
```

Now it’s safe to call it as:

```
def self.decreasing_chat_notification_number(current_user, user)
    # first below is safe, since `unchecked` returns a relation
    #   first called on relation will return nil on empty set
    checking_and_decreasing_notification \
      self.between_chat_recipient(current_user, user).unchecked.first
  end
end
```

*Sidenote*: the postfix form of `if` might be more elegant here:

```
def check_notification #chat notification gets checked
  update_attributes(checked_at: Time.zone.now) if self.checked_at.nil?
end
```